# Confusing Pagination Buttons

Tags: feature-request, design

Isn't this a bit confusing? [image]

I mean button "next" look like label and it's button while "Per page" looks like button and it's label. What do you think?

Comment: You've tagged this as a `feature-request` but you've not suggested a change. What are you proposing as an improvement?

Comment: Yes, change it. Make 'next' looks like other buttons and 'per page' as laber without bacground under it.